# Invalid token in spring boot resource server

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

Hello guys

I need some help in my problem. I can get token from my authorization server.

**That server using Oracle database.

For example

grant_type = client_credentials

clientId = curlclient

clientSecret = test

http://localhost:8885/oauth/token

After, I try to access resource server by the using result access token. But I can't.

Result is:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "b95b8ad3-d030-460d-bee2-ce781b3d4b95"
}
```

Here is my codes:

Resource config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource ouathDataSource(){return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();}

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)throws Exception {
        TokenStore tokenStore=new JdbcTokenStore(ouathDataSource());
        resources.resourceId("product_api").tokenStore(tokenStore);

    }
    @Override

    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/datatest").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')");
    }
}
```

Authorization config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource oauthDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();

    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcClientDetailsService clientDetailsService() {
        return new JdbcClientDetailsService(oauthDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(oauthDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore() {
        return new JdbcApprovalStore(oauthDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
        return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(oauthDataSource());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .approvalStore(approvalStore())
                .authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                .tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }
}
```

WebSecurity config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    private JdbcUserDetails jdbcUserDetails;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(jdbcUserDetails).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Help me!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had recently the same problem and I solved using RemoteTokenServices, it is a bean you add in your implementation of the ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter (@EnableResourceServer).

Basically what it does is indicate to Spring that once the token is received, it will ask to the Auth Server whether that token is valid or not.

The code looks as follow:

```
@Primary
@Bean
public RemoteTokenServices tokenService() {
    RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
    tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(
      "http://localhost:8080/spring-security-oauth-server/oauth/check_token");
    tokenService.setClientId("fooClientIdPassword");
    tokenService.setClientSecret("secret");
    return tokenService;
}
```

For reference you could take a look at this link: [Remote Token Service](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angular)